# Styling SPA mini app for embedding into 3rd party websites

Tags: css, single-page-application

I would like to ship a WordPress plugin that uses an SPA app that connects to an API. The SPA would mostly consist of forms, but I'm having a hard time envisioning the CSS that would be compatible with the number of WordPress themes out there.
Are there some guidelines/sane defaults to make the stylesheet as compatible as it can be with the 3rd party site(s)?
Or should I scrape the idea, and rely on the site admin to delegate the finishing touches to the style of the forms?

Comment: If you are trying to encapsulate your component from styles "bleeding in" from the outside, then you should look into _Shadow DOM_. If you are trying to make your component _adapt_ to how the rest of whatever site it will get used on looks like - then you probably best limit your own formatting to the very minimum.

Comment: I was thinking more along the adapt line, but I guess it is a bit far fetched to hope to be able to cater the layout and the CSS to all the stylesheets out there.